# Replacing commas in thousands/millions but not smaller numbers

Tags: r

I'm reading in data from published papers which have a variety of formats. I want to remove commas in numbers if there are thousands or millions, but not smaller. This is because some authors use a comma to denote the decimal place (e.g., "1,1").

Here's a simple example that is not working:

```
library(stringr)
> text = c('1,1', '2,222', '3,333,333')
> str_replace_all(string=text, pattern='[0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]', replacement = '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
[1] "1,1"                      "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"     "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],333"
```

Ideally the second number would be changed to "2222" and the third "3333333", with the first remaining as "1,1" (I can easily deal with the comma/full-stop issue for decimal places).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead:

```
gsub(",(?=\\d{3,})", "", text, perl = TRUE)
[1] "1,1"     "2222"    "3333333"
```

Here the lookahead `(?=\\d{3,})`is for at least 3 `d`igits following the `,`; if that condition is met, the `,` is removed.

If you prefer `str_remove`, you can use *negative* lookahead:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(text, ",(?!\\d$)")
```

Here the lookahead `(?!\\d$)`disallows the removal of commas **if** they are followed by a single `d`igit before the end (`$`) of the string

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:
It changes the commas to "", if the length of the char is greater than 4.

```
text = c('1,1', '2,222', '3,333,333')

for (i in 1:length(text)) {
          
          if (nchar(text[i]) > 4) {
                    textnew <- as.numeric(gsub(x = text[i], ",", ""))
                    text[i] <- textnew
                    message(i," did a thing")
          } else{
                    message(i," did nothing")
          }
}

text
1 did nothing
2 did a thing
3 did a thing
```

text now looks like this:

```
[1] "1,1"     "2222"    "3333333"
```